# Javascript Logical error - not showing correct answer with guess number

Tags: javascript

So I think I have a logical error in my code that I cant find.

When we type a number higher than **1500** I get the try again message instead of the **Value should be between 1 - 1500**.

And even when I put a number lower than **500** I still get the **Value should be between 1 - 1500** message.

What's the problem here?

```js
var clicks = 0;
var click_max = 1500;
var click_min = 1;

function checkGuess() {
  let txtUserGuess = document.getElementById("userGuess").value;
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("userGuess").innerHTML = clicks;

  console.log(clicks)
  //console.log(txtUserGuess)

  if (clicks <= 6) {
    if (txtUserGuess == 500) {
      swal("Good job!", "Correct answer", "success");
    } else if (txtUserGuess < 500) {
      swal("Oups..", "Try again!", "error");
    } else if (txtUserGuess >= click_max || txtUserGuess <= click_min) {
      swal("Oups..", "Value should be between 1 - 1500", "warning");
    }
  } else {
    swal("No more clicks", "Clicks are done", "error");
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>guessSweet</title>
  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Guess how many Sweets in the jar!</h1>
  <img width="200px" src="jar.png" alt="jar">
  <br>

  <label for="userGuess">Give a number: </label>
  <input pattern="^[0-9]*$" type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" id="userGuess" name="userGuess">
  <button onclick="checkGuess();">Guess</button>

  <script>
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not too clear what you're asking here - stackoverflow questions should be focused around one single problem you're having - what the expected output is and what exactly is going wrong. See - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @GeorgeVasilakis I think you should run and check the code snippet.

Comment: @AtulKumar Yeah, for some strange reason, it's not running on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `txtUserGuess` variable holds a `String`, not a `Number`. Convert it to a `Number` before you compare it against other `Number`s inside your `if`-statemtents. You can use `parseFloat` (or `parseInt` or `Number`) for that. See line 8 in the JS:

```js
var clicks = 0;
var click_max = 1500;
var click_min = 1;

function checkGuess() {
  let txtUserGuess = document.getElementById("userGuess").value;

  txtUserGuess = parseFloat(txtUserGuess); // <-- here

  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("userGuess").innerHTML = clicks;

  console.log(clicks)
  //console.log(txtUserGuess)

  if (clicks <= 6) {
    if (txtUserGuess == 500) {
      swal("Good job!", "Correct answer", "success");
    } else if (txtUserGuess < 500) {
      swal("Oups..", "Try again!", "error");
    } else if (txtUserGuess >= click_max || txtUserGuess <= click_min) {
      swal("Oups..", "Value should be between 1 - 1500", "warning");
    }
  } else {
    swal("No more clicks", "Clicks are done", "error");
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>guessSweet</title>
  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Guess how many Sweets in the jar!</h1>
  <img width="200px" src="jar.png" alt="jar">
  <br>

  <label for="userGuess">Give a number: </label>
  <input pattern="^[0-9]*$" type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" id="userGuess" name="userGuess">
  <button onclick="checkGuess();">Guess</button>

  <script>
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

I noticed that you might have a logical error in your code. If you type a number in the range 501 through to 1499, nothing happens. You need to add conditional branches that handle these numbers, too.